# How to create a histogram using d3.js and crossfilter data?

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

Here's my [demo](http://dev.anuary.com/441bad2f-bcc8-5fe5-af46-f15308f3aee9/) (permanent link; might take a second to load).

I'm having a few problems with it:

1. The crossfilter key does not reflect the upper boundary. Therefore, the x-axis is missing one step.

   [image]

   I managed to fix it by getting one group-step size (`group.all()[1] - group.all()[0]`) and then adding it to the `d3.extent(group.all())[1]`. Because it is a dirty fix, I did not include this to the demo (there might by a data gap). What is a less dirty way to get the group-step size/fix the x-axis?
2. There are uneven gaps between the bars. I can't figure out how to fix x.scale inconsistency with different data sets.

   [image]

   I want the bar-width to adapt automatically to the available graph width. Therefore, I calculate the optimal bar width and then (if needed) resize the graph itself:

   ```
   bar_width = math.round(graph_width/data_length);
   graph_width = bar_width*data_length;
   ```

   Under this condition, there is no way `x.scale` can return uneven data for any key value, yet it does. There is no magic; I am simply overlooking something. But what is it?

   When `x.scale` *is* messed then deducting the `bar_width` from the `graph_width` before setting the `x.scale` range fixes the problem. Though, I can't figure out the condition to detect when x.scale is a not acting as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure the right way to do this. However, I ended up using simple math to guess the upper data boundary. There are many problems that yet remain to be solved, such as how to visually handle extremes.

[image]

My attempt to develop a reusable histogram library is accessible [on github](https://github.com/gajus/interdependent-interactive-histograms).

Comment: This is great! Is there anyway to have it all highlighted by default?

Comment: Haven't touched this in the long time. If you submit an issue/feature request on GitHub, I will take a look at it.